# JS/HTML onChange

Tags: javascript, html

with similar question. :)

```
<input type="text" name="npcolor" id="npcolor" size="9" maxlength="9" value="<?=$userinfo->npcolor?>" onchange="change_npcolor()" readonly />
<input type="text" ID="np_sample" size="2" value="" readonly style="background-color:<?=$userinfo->npcolor?>" />
<input type="button" onclick="pickerPopup202('npcolor','np_sample');" value="Change" />
```

function pickerPopup202 is changing npcolor, but when npcolor is changed it don't call change_npcolor(). When I put extra button that call change_npcolor it works. I tried also:

```
document.getElementById("npcolor").onchange='change_npcolor()';
```

without success.

P.S. JS that changes npcolor (pickerPopup202) isnt mine, and ALL code is at one line, so i cant really mod it.

Comment: chage event doesn't fire on input, when its value is changed via js.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the value dynamically, the onchange event doen't fire. You need to call the `change_npcolor()` method yourself. You could also call `document.getElementById("npcolor").onchange().` (This is less efficient, but more flexible when the event handler may change eventually.)

You cannot change the event listener by just adding a string with javascript code to the onchange property. You can do it like this, however:

```
document.getElementById("npcolor").onchange = function(){
   change_npcolor();
}
```

Comment: You should avoid two elements with the same id, since getElementById might not work properly in that case. What exactly is te problem?

Comment: With a lot of code dividing i modified js. The orig. code was 1 line, 4k symbols. Now it's 120 lines. :) I wanted use onChange if some day i decide to change Color Picker, i just replace it, not modify it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("npcolor").onchange='change_npcolor()';
```

here you have `change_color()` as a string but this is not correct syntax.

Instead of that you can use

```
document.getElementById("npcolor").onchange=change_ncolor;
```

Because the `change_ncolor` works as an object.